# crash at drawInRect:rect, I've the solution but don't know how?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, drawrect

The app works fine with the iphone simulator but when we run it in the actual iphone device it crashes at the following line:

```
[ucdView.image drawInRect:rect];
```

I've searched and found the solution but I don't know how to solve as the time is very short when we have to present it on this Friday. Look at the following solution: 
[Must drawInRect: for a separate context be executed on the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207536/must-drawinrect-for-a-separate-context-be-executed-on-the-main-thread)

The part where this crash happen is in Sculpture.m inside viewDidLoad()

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad]; 

CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
CLController.delegate = self;
[CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];

currentLoc = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redPin.png"]];

UIImage *ucdImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ucd.png"];
self.ucdView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ucdImage];//creating a view for UCD image
ucdView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self loadingFile];

UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[myScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.35];
[myScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
myScrollView.bounces = YES;
myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(1400, 700);
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(ucdImage.size.width, ucdImage.size.height)];
[myScrollView setDelegate:self];
[myScrollView addSubview:ucdView];//adding ucd view to scroll view
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView]; // adding scrollview to self.view main view
[myScrollView release];


//Drawing The Line
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ucdView.frame.size);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, ucdView.frame.size.width, ucdView.frame.size.height);
[ucdView.image drawInRect:rect];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGFloat dashArray[] = {2,0,2,2};
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 3, dashArray, 5);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,[self longt_to_x:[[path_array objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]],[self lat_to_y:[[path_array objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]]);
int path_length = [path_array count];
for(int i = 2; i<path_length; i = i+2){
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,[self longt_to_x:[[path_array objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]],[self lat_to_y:[[path_array objectAtIndex:i+1] doubleValue]]);
}
CGContextStrokePath(context);
ucdView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

}

Thanks a million in advance...

Comment: can you provide the crash log, it'll be helpful ion getting your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say where exactly the crash was, but you have already created one image context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, and then you create another one with `CGBitmapContextCreate`. My guess is that the later one is the problem (getting the arguments right can be tricky) and isn't what you want anyway. So change it to:

```
// Get the current drawing context which is the image context right now
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Comment: Hi Dark, It was before as follows CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  then I changed it as you see the new line but the same it didn't work.... the crash happens at the following line: [ucdView.image drawInRect:rect]; any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Sorry, since you didn't provide a crash log and/or the exact error message I'm afraid I can't help right now. I've got no idea why it would crash at that line.