# How can improve UISlider response for blending mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider, cgcontext

I would use UISlider to adjust the alpha through below codes. However, the response of slider is very slow. How can I improve it?

Thank in advance.

```
-(IBAction)alphaSliderAction:(UISlider*)slider
{

     //blending images
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bgImage.size, YES, 0.0);
    //
     // Use existing opacity as is
       [bgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,bgImage.size.width,bgImage.size.height)];

     [layerAImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,bgImage.size.width,bgImage.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:slider.value];


      finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     //
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     //

      imgView.image=finalImage;

 }
```

Comment: you can try to draw in background thread, use CGBitmapContext as described http://stackoverflow.com/a/3211229/1837959

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the drawing using CoreImage instead of CoreGraphics. The CoreImage [`CIOverlayBlendMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIOverlayBlendMode) filter does the same thing but might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use drawRect at all. Instead, install your image in an image view, and set the alpha property on the image view. You'll need to set the opaque flag on the image view to NO. That will do the blending using the GPU, which should be much faster.

Alternately you could install the image's CGImage in a layer's content property and add that layer to your view. Then you could set the opacity of the layer. You could use the implicit animation on CALayers this way.